# How to create for XML path in sql for table with column name in field_name element and column value in field_value element?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want to create XML like this

```
<root>
<field>
    <field_name>Empname</field_name>
    <field_value>Arul</field_value>
</field>
<field>
    <field_name>Salary</field_name>
    <field_value>1000</field_value>
</field>
<field>
    <field_name>Location</field_name>
    <field_value>Chennai</field_value>
</field>
</root>
```

from table using FOR XML PATH in MS SQL

This is my table:

---

```
|Empname |Salary|Location|
|--------|------|--------|
|Arul    |100   |Chennai | 
|------------------------|
```

Comment: If you want to create XML, then why aren't you? You clearly know that `FOR XML PATH` exists so you know *how* to do it. What is your question here? What have you tried? What were the problems you encountered? Help us help you. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it fail? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little XML within XML ... no need to define the structure.

If doing multiple records, you may want a record node

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (EmpID int,EmpName varchar(50),Salary int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Arul',null)

Select C.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select field_name = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,field_value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Column1','Column2')
             ) C
 For XML Path('field'),Root('root')
```

**Returns**

```
<root>
  <field>
    <field_name>EmpID</field_name>
    <field_value>1</field_value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <field_name>EmpName</field_name>
    <field_value>Arul</field_value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <field_name>Salary</field_name>
    <field_value>100</field_value>
  </field>
</root>
```

> **Edit -** Without the final For XML, you would get

```
field_name  field_value
EmpID       1
EmpName     Arul
Salary      100
```

> **EDITED to included Shnugo's insight to allow nulls**

Comment: Great Bro.. you are awesome. its working.. thank you very much.

Comment: @ArulmuruganK Happy to help.

Comment: I have satisfied with your answer. Thanks for your timely help.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti great solution, +1 from my side. It might be worth to use `FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL` and then `Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./*')`. This would not omit fields with `NULL` values but include them with an empty value.  But this depends on the needs, of course...

Comment: @Shnugo I've traditionally excluded NULL values because are not the same as empty values, but I can see the need to keep the "place marker".  Is there a simple approach to maintain the NULL values vs an Empty String?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Done :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I have another one doubt.. when i covert below xml (this is derived from sql) to json if this XML have more than one element then its converted to json array but single element then its converted to json object. how to i handle this?  I want to handle this on sql side.. is this possible..?

Comment: XML :   `<root>
  <Field>
    <Empname>Arul</Empname>
    <Location>Chennai</Location>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Empname>sam</Empname>
    <Location>Chennai</Location>
  </Field>
</root>`                                                                                                                                          SingleElement XML :  `<root>
  <Field>
    <Empname>Arul</Empname>
    <Location>Chennai</Location>
  </Field> </root>`

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I did not want you to change your approach entirely... It might be perfectly oikay to omit `NULL` values... I just wanted to provide a hint how to include them if needed. In *text-based* containers the `NULL` is difficult to handle. What is `value2` in a CSV with `value1;;value3`? You'd either need some *magic code* (like the `xsi:nil="true"`) or you must rely on the reader to be smart enough. The trick with `ELEMENTS XSINIL` is the way to go, if - whyever - you need the elements of `NULL` values. You know my HTML-table-function? Missing elements would destroy the table there

Comment: @ArulmuruganK, About your *follow-up question*: One principle here on SO is: *One issue - one question*. Your new question should be what it is: A new question. Please start a new question, place a link to this one, tag your question with the appropriate tags (please include SQL-Server's version) and wait for the helping armada to rush in. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Shnugo  I'm new for SO. Thanks for your assist, Bro.

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is great, as it is fully generic. But - especially with many rows (when performance matters) - it might be much easier to *hard-code* your columns. As you know your table's columns I don't know, if a generically running solution is important for you at all...

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (EmpName VARCHAR(100),Salary INT,[Location] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES 
 ('Arul',100,'City 1')
,('One more',200,'City 2');

SELECT 'EmpName' AS [field/field_name]
       ,EmpName AS [field/field_value]
       ,NULL 
       ,'Salary' AS [field/field_name]
       ,Salary AS [field/field_value]
       ,NULL 
       ,'Location' AS [field/field_name]
       ,[Location] AS [field/field_value]
FROM @YourTable 
FOR XML PATH('fields'),ROOT('root');
```

Some remarks:

- The `,NULL` between the lines is a necessary trick to allow multiple elements of the same name within one query (`<field>`).
- This example includes one set in `<fields>` as it returns 2 rows. Don't know if you need this...